# Create form based on EntityType with option to add quantity

Tags: forms, symfony4

I'm trying to setup a Symfony form that will allow a user to select a number of elements adding the wished quantity. I would like to be able to have a `FormType` which would be somewhere between an `EntityType` and the `IntegerType`. Meaning I need to have a list of elements based on a `query_builder` to select only part of my products, but I don't just want to be able to select the product but say how many I want of a given number of products.

I've been able to create a form based on the options I send. For each product in my array I add an `IntegerType` field to my form using the builder. This allows me to show a list of products and ask the client the number of elements he wants.

Now the problem I have is adding detailed data from the product in the list as I don't know the forms field names I can't interact with the label. If I could add something allowing me to say that the `'label'` could show as raw html, I could concatenate the wished data in the label.

Here is my current form:

```php
class OfferRequestStepMultipleHardwareType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // instead of haveing set fields I create them based on the $option['step']->getProducts() data
        foreach ($options['step']->getProducts() as $product){
            $builder->add($product->getId().'-qty', IntegerType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'value' => 0,
                    'class' => 'longlist',
                    'min' => 0
                ],
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'longlist'
                ],
                'label' => $product->getNumber() // ideally I would do some thing like '<div>'.$product->getNumber().'</div><div>'.$product->getDescription().'</div>' and then show it as raw in the form template
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => OfferRequest::class,
            'step' => StepHardware::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is this generates code a bit like this:

```html
<div id="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware">
  <div class="longlist"><label for="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_27-qty" class="required">Product 1</label><input type="number" id="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_27-qty" name="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware[27-qty]" required="required" value="0" class="longlist"
      min="0"></div>
  <div class="longlist"><label for="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_28-qty" class="required">Product 2</label><input type="number" id="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_28-qty" name="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware[28-qty]" required="required" value="0" class="longlist"
      min="0"></div>
  <div class="longlist"><label for="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_29-qty" class="required">Product 3</label><input type="number" id="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_29-qty" name="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware[29-qty]" required="required" value="0" class="longlist"
      min="0"></div>
  <div class="longlist"><label for="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_30-qty" class="required">Product 4</label><input type="number" id="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware_30-qty" name="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware[30-qty]" required="required" value="0" class="longlist"
      min="0"></div><input type="hidden" id="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware__token" name="offer_request_step_multiple_hardware[_token]" value="PZaPfxKNSV-TjftRgjAw1K8XCUr7Dvkrp57kWTMBJ64"></div>
```

I've also tried to create a form theming in the template to change the way the Integer widget show with this:

```twig
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block question %}
    <h1>{{ offer.lastStep.Question }}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="name_row">
        {{ form_label(form)|raw }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_help(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Without any success as when I concatenate and try to add the filter "raw" to it, the code is still changed autoescaped. The problem is then I've found information on how to set a specific label for a specific field of a form, but again I generate the form on the go and have no way of knowing the field names (like described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)). Any suggestions on how to have this work?

Ideally I would like to be able to create a FormType based on the EntityType which would allow to add an Integer instead of selecting the Entity elements...

Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

Labels in Symfony forms are escaped at some point before the rendering of the template, so applying the twig `raw` filter won't prevent html entities from being escaped.

What you can do is create a new twig filter, to apply the php function [html-entity-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.html-entity-decode.php) (following code untested):

**Twig/HtmlDecodeExtension.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class HtmlDecodeExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('htmldecode', [$this, 'htmlDecode']),
        ];
    }

    public function htmlDecode($value)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($value);
    }
}
```

If you use the default configuration with services autowiring, [you don't have to register the new extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service); in the other case, do it in `config/services.yaml`

Now you can use the filter in your form template instead of `raw`, and put whatever html you like in the label:

```html
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block question %}
    <h1>{{ offer.lastStep.Question }}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="name_row">
        {{ form_label(form)|htmldecode }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_help(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```